# Scaling website content to resolution and window size in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, resolution

This is my first week of programming in CSS, HTML and PHP... I realized when beginning my site that when i scaled my site by window size that all the text would begin to overlap, cause issues and look terrible.

I was wondering if i could get a clear answer on what i am doing horribly wrong. I have tried methods such as media queries but i still don't understand it at all.

Here is my HTML...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
```

```
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />

  <title>replay.sc</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<style type="text/css">


a:link { color: grey; }
a:visited { color: grey; }
a:hover { color: white; }
a:active { color: grey; }
text-decoration: none;
```

}
}

```
</style>


  </head>

  <body font="sans-serif"  id="container">


    <!--- BEGIN: STICKY HEADER -->
    <div id="header_container">
        <div id="header">
            <p><a  id="headertext"  a href="replay.sc"> replay.sc </a><p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END: STICKY HEADER -->

    <!-- BEGIN: Sticky Footer -->
    <div id="footer_container">
        <div id="footer">

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END: Sticky Footer -->
    <div id="home_container">
    <h1 id="hometext" > Upload your replay here to generate a page containing a download link and various information on the replay. </h1>
        <p id="hometext2"> When the page is generated you will have the option to select which information on the replay you want to display to the public, if you are logged in you will be able to edit this in the future.</p>

    <h1 id="hometext3"> Upload a replay pack here to generate a page containing download links for every replay or for a .rar file of every replay. </h1>
        <p id="hometext4"> Only basic information for each replay will be made to conserve server load. </p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

and my CSS

```
/* Reset body padding and margins */
body { margin:0px; padding:0px; }

/* Make Header Sticky */
#header_container { background:black; border:1px solid #666; height:40px;left:0;position:fixed; width:100%; top:0; }
#header{ line-height:5px; margin:10px; auto:width:940px; text-align:left;}
#headertext { 
font-family: "sans-serif";
size: 20px;
padding: 2px;
font-size: 120%; 
text-decoration: none;
}

/* CSS for the content of page. I am giving top and bottom padding of 80px to make sure the header and footer do not overlap the content.*/
#container{ margin:auto; overflow:auto; padding:80px ; width:100%; height: auto; }
#content{
}

 /* CSS FOR HOME PAGE CONTENTS */

#hometext{
font-family: "arial";
padding: 1px;
font-size: 100%; 
text-decoration: none;
position: absolute;
top: 5em; 
left: 4em; 
color: #585858;
margin-right: 850px;
 }

#hometext2 {
font-family: "arial";
padding: 10px;
font-size:80%; 
text-decoration: none;
position: absolute;
top: 7em; 
left: 4.24em; 
color: #585858;
margin-right: 1200px; 
}

#hometext3 {
font-family: "arial";
padding: 1px;
font-size:100%; 
text-decoration: none;
position: absolute;
top: 5m; 
left: 65em; 
color: #585858;
margin-right: 0; 
}

#hometext4 {
font-family: "arial";
padding: 18px;
font-size:80%; 
text-decoration: none;
position: absolute;
top: 10m; 
left: 80em; 
color: #585858;
margin-right: 0; 
}

#home_container
```

Comment: A little tip. Look into what the difference is between fluid, adaptive and responssive design. Start by trying to change it to a fluid design (use % in width). Then look into adaptive design and lastly responssive. Another good idea would be to start with the most minimalist case you can think of. Like two divs besides one another. The main issue is the misuse of absolute position. Look into float

Comment: Why are you posting this again?!

Comment: Agreed with @RonniSkansing.

Try using `position: relative` instead of `absolute` so your text doesn't bunch up like that. Also it seems as though you want some type of column layout with a sidebar. I would wrap your `#hometext` and `#hometext2` in a div called `.main` or something, and the other 2 in a div called `.sidebar`. From there you can style each and position them a bit better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [making my site scale to resolution sizes in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819713/making-my-site-scale-to-resolution-sizes-in-css)

Comment: Also you should name your divs a little better, you shouldn't even need to use ids. If you are making `.main` and `.sidebar` as I suggested, then you give `#hometext` a class of `.header` and `#hometext2` a class of `.content` or something. Do this for the divs inside `.sidebar` and you can then add common styles for both `.header`'s and `.content` as well as target specific divs by using `.main .header` etc.